# List all layers within an .aprx and export all to a .gdb

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, export, file-geodatabase

I would like to export all layers within an .aprx to a .gdb.

This is the script:

```
# Set the .aprx file as the workspace
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"B:\XXX000\XXX35219_BCG\Workspaces\EIAR\Chapter 7 - Air Quality\Chapter 7 - Air Quality.aprx")

# Set the output workspace to the .gdb file
arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace = r"B:\XXX000\XXX35219_ABC\Workspaces\EIAR\Chapter 7 - Air Quality\Default.gdb"

# Get a list of all the data in the .aprx file
data_list = aprx.listTables() + aprx.listFeatureClasses() + aprx.listRasters()

# Loop through the data list and export each item to the .gdb file
for data in data_list:
    arcpy.FeatureClassToGeodatabase_conversion(data, arcpy.env.scratchWorkspace)

print("Export complete")
```

This is the error that follows:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 10, in
>  AttributeError: 'ArcGISProject' object has no attribute
> 'listTables'

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways you can list tables --

1. [ListTables](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listtables.htm) from the **workspace**

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "path to fGDB"
arcpy.ListTables()
```

2. [listTables](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/mapping/map-class.htm) from the **map** object

```
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r"B:\XXX000\XXX35219_BCG\Workspaces\EIAR\Chapter 7 - Air Quality\Chapter 7 - Air Quality.aprx")
m = aprx.listMaps()[0] # Will use the first map it finds in the project
m.listTables()
```

Your code is attempting to list tables on the Project (`aprx`), which does not have a List Tables function.

You'll need to have a 2nd look at your `aprx.listFeatureClasses() + aprx.listRasters()` bit of code as well. I know these don't exist off the `aprx`, however they may have their own answer as to where to find them which is different than the **tables**.

After that, you're trying to take a list of many different things (tables, feature classes, rasters) and use the **FeatureClass** to Geodatabase tool to copy them. I hope you see how throwing a *raster* into the *feature class* tool is going to fail. You aren't going to accomplish what you want with a single, simple bit of code.